# IntelliJ IDEA shortcut for switching to tab by number

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

In FireFox, I'm constantly using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> shortcut to switch tabs. Basically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> will take me to the first tab, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> will take me to the second one and so on.

Is there an equivalent for this shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: I always find myself going back to Sublime Text 2 because it supports this OOTB - makes me sad I can't do it in PhpStorm :(

Comment: As https://stackoverflow.com/a/52706501 shows, there are now keyboard shortcuts you can set for Select Tab 1 etc.! But you might also prefer to set numbered bookmarks with Ctrl+Shift+1 etc., and jump to them with Ctrl+1; while not quite the same, this is robust to changing tab ordering!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

You can now assign keyboard shortcuts to navigate to the specific tab number:

[image: Select Tab]

---

Original obsolete response:

There is no such feature in IDEA, however you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Arrows and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> (Recent Files) to navigate between tabs.

Other handy actions from the Go To menu:

- Back / Forward (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>)
- Last Edit Location (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>)

---

Another option is to use the [GoToTabs](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7784-gototabs) third-party plug-in:

> The plugin adds menu actions allowing you to go to a specific tab. You
> can of course assign keyboard shortcuts the individual actions and for
> example achieve the behavior known from other editors/IDEs where you
> can switch between tabs with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>num</kbd>.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Last edit location doesn't seem to be working at all. I've tried to change the hotkeys. What is supposed to do? I expected it to work as a "go back"  and "go forward" but more sensitive.

Comment: @momo this feature works fine, just checked. It will navigate you to the last file/position that was edited. If it doesn't work for you, please submit a ticket to support.

Comment: @CrazyCoder you are right, it does work, i had the hotkeys overriden in ubuntu

Comment: Plugin GoToTabs now says "DEPRECATED".

Comment: It says deprecated because the IDE has got built-in support to set up these shortcuts. Go to `Preferences > Keymap > Other > Tabs`

Answer (score 33):

The IDE itself still doesn't support it but I've created a plugin ([`GoToTabs`](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7784)) that will add "Go to tab #" actions you can assign keyboard shortcuts to (e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>).

Comment: Cool! Thanks @JiříPospíšil! Would also be nice to have the ability to jump to the last tab...

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a ton. A short tutorial on how to get this working:  

```Get the plugin```,  
```Go to preferences -> keymap```,  
```Search for 'tab'```,  
```Map the various 'goto tab#' to 'cmd+numberkey'```

Comment: @RomanBataev The functionality has been added as part of the 1.3 release.

Answer (score 19):

you also can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to active switcher

after <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> and keep holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> for other operations

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + number is for bookmarks feature.

Answer (score 18):

Since this is one of the first hits when Googling this, note that as of IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 EAP this is now possible. From the [feature request tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68324#focus=streamItem-27-3067389-0-0):

> In upcoming 2018.3 EAPs you're welcome to assign shortcuts you need for new actions in the group 'Other', see a screenshot. With these actions you can select tab1..tab9 and also the last tab.

To accomplish this:

1. Go to Keymap in Preferences
2. Search for "select tab"
3. Individually assign `Command+<number>` to each of the tab numbers mappings

[image: Screenshot of tab keymapper]

Answer (score 11):

You can use this short cut on mac
`Shift` + `Command` + `{` or `}`

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what you asking is possible but **Navigate as below in intellij idea (13)** to **switch tabs** in one level,

```
File
└────Settings
     └─────────Keymap
               └────── Editor Tabs
```

Where yo can map for actions **"Select Next Tab"** and **"Select Previous Tab"**, under **"Editor tabs"** in **keymaps**. Following is an example for `emacs` keymap.

[image: Editor tabs shortcuts]

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> - go to previous tab
<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> - go to next tab

Comment: Does this no longer work? Or do you have to be in a particular keyboard mapping collection? It does not seem to work anymore, and I cannot seem to find the mapping that enables it.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is an option, pressing Alt + Tab a switcher will pop up. 
Like this:

[[image: 1]]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IntelliJ's [IdeaVim plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164-ideavim), the vim style shortcut works as well:

1. `gt`, go to next tab
2. `gT`, go to the previous tab
3. `1gt`, go to the first tab
4. `2gt`, go to the second tab
5. `3gt`, ....

Answer (score 0):

If a tab has a number with an underline like [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFcUa.png), you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> to switch to it. But not all tabs have a underlined number.

Answer (score 0):

**MacOS**:

- Next tab: <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>
- Previous tab: <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

Comment: This is annoying and highlights Windows-centric JetBrains' blindspot when it comes to Macs. 

This should be ⌘← / ⌘→ like every other sensible editor on the planet.

Answer (score 0):

if you use ideavim, you can use num+gt to go to the specific tab. for example, 2gt lead you to the second tab.

Answer (score 0):

Keymap -> Other -> Tabs.
Then setup what you want

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to switch between menu tabs (**menu such as Git**) then the shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd>