# How can you map .ideavimrc to switch between tabs in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

In intellij with the vim plugin. I am trying to switch between tabs from within from rather than using intellij's default setup of alt+left and alt+right to switch between tabls.
I would like to map Control+H to Alt+left arrow.
And also Control+L to Alt+right arrow.

What would I put into my .ideavimrc file?

Answer (score 6):

You can change the mapping to switch between tabs using `Idea` or `ideaVim` as follows

##### The Idea way

- `Settings` > `Keymap`
- Search for `select next tab`
- Change the mapping to what you like

##### The ideaVim way

- Open `search everywhere` > `Actions`
- Type `track action id` and enable the corresponding option
- Type `select next tab` and run the corresponding action
- You will find the action id at the left bottom area or in Notifications. Add it to `.ideavimrc` like

  ```
  nmap <c-l> <Action>(NextTab)
  ```

Comment: Track action id cannot track <Alt-Left> and <Alt-right> action id

Comment: <Alt-Left> and <Alt-right> are `keymaps` rather than `actions`. If you want to check whether they are handled by Idea or IdeaVim to any action, you can try `Settings > Keymap` or `Settings > Editor > Vim`.

Comment: For anyone who is curious about the reverse operation, it is `nmap <c-h> <Action>(PreviousTab)` (replace c-h with the keybinding you want)

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to do that, but instead of Next/Previous select an exact tab you want? Sth like <Action>(Tab1)

Comment: You can see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3369067/5154601. Looks like `<Action>(GoToTab1)`